# Equivalence statement of locally compact

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\mathscr{T})$ be a topological space. Then the following are equivalent:

- $\forall x\in X,~\exists~\text{compact}~G\subseteq X,~x\in G^o$
- $\forall x\in X,~\exists~\text{open set}~U\subseteq X,~x\in U\subseteq \overline{U}$ and $\overline{U}$ is compact

If it were LCH, I know how to prove it. However, it is only locally compact. (The problem is came from our teacher's exercise.) I guess the equivalent is a mistake. Isn't it?

Comment: Short comment: Some authors include hausdorffness in the definition of locally compact space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $(\Bbb N,\tau)$ where $\tau=\{A\subseteq \Bbb N\,:\, A=\emptyset\lor 0\in A\}$. This topological space satisfies the first one because $G:=\{x,0\}$ is open and compact, but not the second one, because all non-empty open sets are dense and $(\Bbb N,\tau)$ is not compact.

Is is clear, though, that the second one implies the first one by considering $G=\overline U$.

Comment: Thanks for the couterexample!